# generating combination with many product attribute in prestashop

Tags: php, sql, e-commerce, prestashop

I have many product attributes like this

> 1. part 1:
>
>    - black
>    - tan
>    - espresso
>    - grey
>    - navy
>    - red
> 2. part 2:
>
>    - black
>    - tan
>    - espresso
>    - grey
>    - navy
>    - red
> 3. part 3:
>
>    - black
>    - tan
>    - espresso
>    - grey
>    - navy
>    - red
> 4. part 4:
>
>    - black
>    - tan
>    - espresso
>    - grey
>    - navy
>    - red
> 5. Sole:
>
>    - Leather
>    - rubber
>    - creppy
>    - leather with half rubber
>    - leather with lug sole
>    - cristy sole
> 6. size:
>
>    - 39
>    - 40
>    - 41
>    - 42
>    - 43
>    - 44
>    - 45

I tried creating combinations with combination generator,but that does not help, the query does not run everything, may be due to time out or whatever it is.

database struktur:

```
- attribute_product :
id | name
1  | part_1
2  | part_2
3  | part_3
4  | part_4
5  | sole
6  | size

- sub_attribute_product :
id | id_atribute_product | name
1  |         1           | tan
2  |         1           | black
.. |        ...          | ...
4  |         5           | leather
5  |         5           | rubber
.. |        ...          | ...
7  |         6           | 39
.. |        ...          | ...
```

> output :
>
> size: 39, sole: leather, part1: tan, part2: tan, part3: black, part4: tan

The point is I want to create an automated query "create into .... " of more than 5000 ++, is it possible?

Comment: Can you kindly share your sample desired output?

Comment: like this, SOLE - Leather, part1 - black, part2 - Black, part3 - Black, part4 - black , SOLE - Leather, part1 - grey, part2 - Black, part3 - Black, part4 - black, etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table `sub_attribute_product` has attribute data as below.

```
id | id_atribute_product |   name 
--------------------------------------------------- 
1        1                   black
2        1                   tan
3        1                   espresso
4        1                   grey
5        1                   navy
6        1                   red
7        2                   black
8        2                   tan
9        2                   espresso
10       2                   grey
11       2                   navy
12       2                   red
13       3                   black
14       3                   tan
15       3                   espresso
16       3                   grey
17       3                   navy
18       3                   red
19       4                   black 
20       4                   tan
21       4                   espresso
22       4                   grey
23       4                   navy
24       4                   red
25       5                   Leather 
26       5                   rubber
27       5                   creppy
28       5                   leather with half rubber
29       5                   leather with lug sole 
30       5                   cristy sole 
31       6                   39
32       6                   40
33       6                   41
34       6                   42
35       6                   43
36       6                   44
37       6                   45
```

You can retrieve each attribute rows one by one in sub tables and cross join all as below.

```
SELECT concat('size: ',t6.name,', sole: ',t5.name,', part1: ',t1.name,', part2: ',t2.name,', part3: ',t3.name,', part4: ',t4.name) AS RESULT
    FROM
      (SELECT *
       FROM table2 t2
       WHERE t2.id_attrib = 1) t1
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT *
       FROM table2 t2
       WHERE t2.id_attrib = 2) t2
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT *
       FROM table2 t2
       WHERE t2.id_attrib = 3) t3
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT *
       FROM table2 t2
       WHERE t2.id_attrib = 4) t4
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT *
       FROM table2 t2
       WHERE t2.id_attrib = 5) t5
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT *
       FROM table2 t2
       WHERE t2.id_attrib = 6) t6;
```

The above query will generate `6*6*6*6*6*7 = 54432` combinations as below sample. the query is valid for `mySQL`. If you are using another `rdbms` you need to probably tweak it e.g. add `AS` keyword or use `||` or `+` instead of `concat` etc.

```
Result
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: black, part2: black, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: tan, part2: black, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: espresso, part2: black, part3: black, part4: black
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: grey, part2: black, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: navy, part2: black, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: red, part2: black, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: black, part2: tan, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: tan, part2: tan, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: espresso, part2: tan, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: grey, part2: tan, part3: black, part4: black 
size: 39, sole: Leather , part1: navy, part2: tan, part3: black, part4: black 
.....................
.....................and so on
```

You can check the demo [**here**](http://rextester.com/VMD24604)

Hope this will help.

Comment: I think it seems impossible because it will change the existing structure in another module

Comment: @BayuRizkiIsnaeniHidayatuloh: What the current schema structure? As it was not included in question, so i solved it on the basis of assumption.

Comment: I have changed the question

Comment: @BayuRizkiIsnaeniHidayatuloh. We always recommend to include complete schema. I will start assumptions again. e.g. Is `tan`, `black` attributes exists once in table or 4 times. Can you kindly include complete sample `product_attributes` table in your question. ?

Comment: I am also confused with the structure of this scheme because this is a cms structure scheme not made by me but I try to understand it, essentially if part1, part2 there are 6 data, part3 there 6 data, part4 there are 6 data, sole there are 7 data , and size there are 7 data. it will multiply 6 * 6 * 6 * 6 * 7 * 7 and generate 63504 new queries and in prestashop already give generator combination but only generated 3100, how to make it all regenerated, sorry for bad english

Comment: @BayuRizkiIsnaeniHidayatuloh: check my updated answer. i think it will help :-)